# AC universal motor changed rotation direction after armature rewinding

Tags: universal-motor

I repaired the armature of my juicer machine by rewinding it because it got burnt.

The machine should rotate clockwise in order to operate normally, but after rewinding, it is now rotating anti-clockwise causing the nut holding on the shaft to loosen.

I searched for the solution online and the only solution I got is to swap the connections to the brushes and I did it, but this solution causes high sparks in brushes and poor rotation speed with too heat generating.

What is wrong? Did I make mistake in rewinding the armature? Is rewinding direction determining also rotation direction? What is proper direction of rewinding the armature so that it can rotate clockwise?

Comment: Reposition the brushes to minimise sparking. If the motor allows for that.

Comment: I hv done that but no avail... I think I made mistake in rewinding... when I place brushes as normal no sparks but sparks appear when I switch the rerminals of brush..

Comment: No, having reversed the motor by rewiring the brushes, you need to physically move the brushes to find the new neutral position. If  the motor lets you do that. https://www.manufacturing.net/home/article/13216590/motors-week-brushes-sparking-and-machine-maintenance

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can rewind a motor in the opposite direction and it will rotate backwards.

You can also miswire the windings to the commutator plates and change the [optimal angle between the brushes and the stator winding or magnets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brushed_DC_electric_motor#Compensation_for_stator_field_distortion).

Sparking and heat in only one direction means that the aforementioned angle is near-optimal for the reverse operation and profoundly wrong for the other one.

What could have gone wrong?

The most probable cause is that you mis-mounted the back of the motor (with the brushes assembly) and it is rotated at some angle in respect to its original position. E.g. 180 degrees?